# FileNotFoundException when invoking RESTful service

Tags: java, rest

A simple REST invocation I have set up is giving me a file-not-found exception when running. I've looked up the error and know that the URL isn't finding anything, but I can't figure out why. The REST servlet seems to me to be set up just fine yet somehow the URL isn't mapping to the actions implemented inside it. A similar tutorial project works perfectly, but not this one, even though they're configured in almost exactly the same way:

Output:

```
{"username":"AchillesV3","password":"affirmation","email":"jason@cave-gaming.com"}

Error while calling Crunchify REST Service
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/arenamaster-backend/api/player/post
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/arenamaster-backend/api/player/post
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1890)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at RESTServiceClient.main(RESTServiceClient.java:43)
```

PlayerService.java

```
package services;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;

import objects.*;

@Path("/player")
public class PlayerService {

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    //@CrossOrigin
    public String getTestString() {

        return "Get success";

    }

    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    //@CrossOrigin
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response registerNewPlayer(PlayerRegisterRequest new_player) {

        String result = "Player saved : " + new_player;
        return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();

    }

}
```

Rest Client:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;

public class RESTServiceClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "";
        try {

            // Step1: Let's 1st read file from fileSystem
            // Change CrunchifyJSON.txt path here
            InputStream crunchifyInputStream = new FileInputStream("JSON.txt");
            InputStreamReader crunchifyReader = new InputStreamReader(crunchifyInputStream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(crunchifyReader);
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                string += line + "\n";
            }

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(string);
            System.out.println(jsonObject);

            // Step2: Now pass JSON File Data to REST Service
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/arenamaster-backend/api/player/post");
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
                OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                out.write(jsonObject.toString());
                out.close();

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

                String line_in;

                while ((line_in = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line_in);
                }
                System.out.println("\nCrunchify REST Service Invoked Successfully..");
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("\nError while calling Crunchify REST Service");
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(e);
            }

            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>services</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out by making following changes in Player class :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/arenamaster-backend/api/player/")
public class PlayerService {

}
```

And add `@Produces` annotation with proper return content type to `registerNewPlayer` method in this it will be :

```
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
```

And rather than

```
    InputStream crunchifyInputStream = new FileInputStream("JSON.txt");
```

give full path of the file `JSON.txt` 
like

```
InputStream crunchifyInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\JSON.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by making a new project using Maven's command line protocol. It seems like the error was with the file structure.